# C#.net MVC Passing parameter to load data from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I wanted to pass a value I got from my **angular** **checkboxes** .. ( number that has been checked) to query a certain data from my db.
Take a look on my connection query ..

```
private static string m_sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NomsConnection"].ConnectionString;
    private static string
        m_sReport = "SELECT r.[RequestID],r.[RequestDate],r.[PARNumber],r.[StatusID],r.[PurchaseComment]"   // 0 - 4
                    + ",r.[UID],r.[LearUID],r.[FullName],r.[Email]"                                // 5 - 8
                    + ",r.[EntityName],r.[DepartmentName],r.[DepartmentID]"                // 9 - 11
                    + ",r.[InboxLearUID]"                                                                // 12

                    + ",r.[ProgramID],r.[ProgramCode],r.[ProgramName],r.[CostCenterCode]"             // 13 - 16
                    + ",p.[PartDesc],p.[SupplierID],p.[AccountType],p.[CurrName],p.[PartQuantity],p.[PiecePrice], p.[PartNumber]"
                    + "FROM [NOP_PR].[dbo].[Requests] r "
                    + "JOIN [NOP_PR].[dbo].[Parts] p on p.[RequestID] = r.[RequestID]"
                    + "JOIN [NOP_PR].[dbo].[Departments] d on d.[DepartmentID] = r.[DepartmentID]"
                    + "WHERE [CountryName] IN ('Philippines') ";
    //ORDER BY r.[RequestDate] DESC"; 




public static List<NomsPRRequest> LoadPRfromDB_withParams(DateTime from, DateTime to, string EntityID,
            string DepartmentID, string [] StatusID)
        {
            string sScript = m_sReport + ((EntityID == "") ? "" : " AND d.[EntityID]=" + EntityID) + ((DepartmentID == "") ? "" : " AND d.[DepartmentID]=" + DepartmentID)
                + " and [RequestDate] between '" + from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' and '" + to.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'" + " and " + ((  __________ ) ? "" : " AND d.[StatusID] in (" + ____________ + ")"  );


            Dictionary<long, NomsPRRequest> data = new Dictionary<long, NomsPRRequest>();
            long key;
            double dAmount;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(m_sConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sScript, con))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        key = reader.GetInt64(0);
                        if (!data.ContainsKey(key))
                        {
                            data.Add(key, new NomsPRRequest()
                            {
                                RequestID = key,
                                RequestDate = reader.GetDateTime(1),
                                PARNumber = reader.GetString(2),
                                DepartmentName = reader.GetString(10),
                                DepartmentID = reader.GetInt64(11),
                                StatusID = reader.GetInt64(3),
                                FullName = reader.GetString(7),
                                InboxLearUID = reader.GetString(12),
                                ProgramName = reader.GetString(14),
                                ItemList = new List<NomsPRItem>(),
                                TotalAmount = 0.0
                            });
                        }
                        dAmount = (double)reader.GetDecimal(21) * (double)reader.GetDecimal(22);
                        data[key].TotalAmount += dAmount;
                        data[key].ItemList.Add(new NomsPRItem()
                        {
                            RequestID = key,
                            PartDesc = reader.GetString(17),
                            PartNumber = reader.GetString(23),
                            SupplierID = reader.GetString(18),
                            FullName = reader.GetString(7),
                            AccountType = reader.GetString(19),
                            CurrName = reader.GetString(20),
                            PartQuantity = (double)reader.GetDecimal(21),
                            PiecePrice = (double)reader.GetDecimal(22),
                            Amount = dAmount
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            return data.Values.ToList();
        }
```

and that's it .. the query with underline is what I wanted to solve.

```
string sScript = m_sReport + ((EntityID == "") ? "" : " AND d.[EntityID]=" + EntityID) + ((DepartmentID == "") ? "" : " AND d.[DepartmentID]=" + DepartmentID)
            + " and [RequestDate] between '" + from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' and '" + to.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'" + " and " + ((  __________ ) ? "" : " AND d.[StatusID] in (" + ____________ + ")"  );
```

And also what to pass in my MVC Controller.

```
public JsonResult GetList()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        List<NomsPRRequest> model = NomsConnection.LoadPRfromDB_withParams(new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0), today,"","");

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetReportList(string from, string to, string EntityID="", string DepartmentID="", int StatusID)
    {
        DateTime fromd = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime tod = DateTime.Now;
        if (from != "undefined")
            fromd = Convert.ToDateTime(from);
        if (to != "undefined")
            tod = Convert.ToDateTime(to);
        fromd = new DateTime(fromd.Year, fromd.Month, fromd.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        tod = new DateTime(tod.Year, tod.Month, tod.Day, 23, 59, 59);
        return Json(NomsConnection.LoadPRfromDB_withParams(fromd, tod, EntityID, DepartmentID, StatusID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is my view

```
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
                            <li data-ng-repeat="item in StatusList">
                                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" data-checklist-value="1" data-checklist-model="filter.StatusID" />
                                    {{item}}
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

and my angular

```
        scope.array_ = angular.copy(scope.array);
        scope.getStatus = http.get('GetStatusList').success(function (status) {
            scope.StatusList = status;

        });


        PRApp.directive("checkboxGroup", function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    // Determine initial checked boxes
                    if (scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id) !== -1) {
                        elem[0].checked = true;
                    }

                    // Update array on click
                    elem.bind('click', function () {
                        var index = scope.array.indexOf(scope.item.id);
                        // Add if checked
                        if (elem[0].checked) {
                            if (index === -1) scope.array.push(scope.item.id);
                        }
                            // Remove if unchecked
                        else {
                            if (index !== -1) scope.array.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                        // Sort and update DOM display
                        scope.$apply(scope.array.sort(function (a, b) {
                            return a - b
                        }));
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Also what to add in this part when passing the data....

```
        scope.changeDate = function () {
            scope.models = null;
            var e = document.getElementById("entityList");
            scope.EntityID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            e = document.getElementById("deptList");
            scope.DepartmentID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            // console.log(this.filter_fromDate);
            //console.log(this.filter_toDate);
            http.get('GetReportList?from=' + scope.filter_fromDate + '&to=' + scope.filter_toDate + '&EntityID=' + scope.EntityID + '&DepartmentID=' + scope.DepartmentID).success(
                function (data) {
                    scope.models = data;
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your sql queries really should be [parameterised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements) to prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Given that it seems that your problem is that you need your query to read `.... AND d.statusid IN ( [status1], [status2], [status3] ......)`. To do this you can use parameters. First of all we need to set a parameter up for each string in `StatusId`

```
 string sScript = m_sReport 
    + ((EntityID == "") ? "" : " AND d.[EntityID]=" 
    + EntityID) + ((DepartmentID == "") ? "" : " AND d.[DepartmentID]=" 
    + DepartmentID) + " and [RequestDate] between '" 
    + from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' and '" 
    + to.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'" + " and " 
    + ((  __________ ) ? "" : " AND d.[StatusID] in (";

int paramCount=0;
foreach(string Id in StatusId)
{

   sScript = sScript + "@statusParam" + paramCount + ",";
   paramCount++;
}
sScript = sScript + ");";
```

next we need to fill the each parameter, so after we've initialised the connection etc:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sScript, con))
{
    paramCount = 0;
    foreach(string Id in StatusId)
    {
        string paramName = "@statusParam" + paramCount;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName,Id);
        paramCount++;
    }
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    /*..........rest of the code */
}
```

I've not stuck this in any IDE so there may be minor syntax errors, but you get the idea.

Comment: did you mean by the statusId in here ` foreach(string Id in StatusId)` is the StatusID i'll get from my checkboxes ?

Comment: Your method `LoadPRfromDB_withParams` contains a parameter `string[] StatusId`. I assumed that your problem was writing a query to include all statusIds in that array. Your question isn't terribly clear - Are you struggling with getting the checkboxes to post back to the controller, or with writing the SQL query?